# Is Spring Batch suitable to periodically delete records from DB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a complete Spring Boot project, and I need to delete records from database under specific conditions every 48 hours.

I have to meet a deadline, is it worth it to learn and use Spring Batch for this purpose or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: yes Spring boot is for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new Spring Bean using the `@Component` annotation or reuse a service bean. Then, implement a method to delete this records and use the `@scheduled` annotation to configure when this method has to be executed.

Don't forget to add the `@EnableAsyng` annotation on your Spring Boot configuration class

Visit the Spring site and find for Scheduling documentation

Comment: thank you, i'll check it in a few hours,
Tell me please, what if i want to learn Spring Batch and add it to my skill set, is this task (periodically delete stuff from DB) a good use case of spring batch or is spring batch used for other kinds of tasks ?

Comment: Spring batch is used usually to execute batch process with chains of jobs. You can stop jobs, restart, review jobs executions, etc. If you only wants to execute a process every N hours, is not necessary use Spring Batch.